# Is there any way to load the Egyptian characters as text into the table using a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

when I am loading `.CSV` file into the database table, the column values with Egyptian characters are getting loaded as `?`; only `?` characters are appearing in the table after loading.

MySQL server

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
   identifier varchar(255),
   object varchar(255),
   date_min varchar,
   date_max varchar,
   Provenance_toponym  varchar(255),
   tm_geo int,
   scribe_name varchar(255),
   fathers_name varchar(255),
   spellings varchar(255),
   lemma_reference varchar(255),
   transliteration varchar(255),
   translation varchar(255)
 );

create database subscribe1
character set utf8
collate ut8_unicode_ci
```

I expect the output as  'ḥsb.t' but the actual output is '????'

Comment: Output of what? I'm pretty sure `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE DATABASE`, `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` cannot have `'ḥsb.t'` as output.

Comment: then how to convert the egiptian characters to text and load into the table

Comment: Are you sure you are running `CREATE DATABASE` before `CREATE TABLE` ? Are you sure CSV is encoded in UTF-8 ? Are you sure the client encoding is set to UTF-8 when importing into the table ?

Comment: Please show an example of how you are filling the database (including the sample data), and how you're outputting. It is impossible to tell anything without the code (except, possibly, that you might be using either a wrong encoding for your terminal, or a wrong font.) Also, there's nothing particularly Egyptian-characterish in `'ḥsb.t'`. Do you mean [Egyptian hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_(Unicode_block)), or Latin transliteration of Egyptian Arabic as you have shown?

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/nikitha/test_sample.csv" INTO TABLE nikitha.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(identifier,object,date_min,max,provenance_toponym,tm_geo,scribe_name,fathers_name,spellings,lemma_reference,transliteration,translation);

Comment: this is the query and im trying  to load the data into database using csv file

Comment: yes they are Egyptian hieroglyphs and im trying to load the csv file containing Egyptian hieroglyphsin one of the column and they are getting loaded as "????".

Comment: In order to determine exactly where the problem is, please execute `SELECT HEX(hieroglyph_field) FROM nikitha.test LIMIT 1` where `hieroglyph_field` is the field that contains hieroglyphics, and report the result.